# I could not figure out how get out of infinite loop

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

This is code with multiple loops i need to fix this infinite loop. Can anyone fix it?

```
.data   



 a dword 10

 b dword 1

 d dword 35



 delta dword ?
.code

main PROC

  call clrscr

  mov dh,0

  mov ecx,10

  push ecx

  row:
mov dl,01
mov ecx, a
mov eax,'*'
line:

       call gotoxy

       call writechar

       inc dl

    loop line



    mov ecx, b

    mov eax,'p'

   line1:

     call gotoxy

     call writechar

     inc dl

   loop line1

   mov ecx, d

    mov eax,'c'

   line2:

     call gotoxy

     call writechar

     inc dl

   loop line2

   inc dh

   mov dl,1

   dec a

   inc b

   inc b

   dec d

   dec d

   dec d

   pop ecx

  loop row
```

Help with infinite loop.

Comment: This is giving me an infinite loop. does anyone has any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `loop` instruction to make nested loops!

I don't know why, but recently on SO, there are many beginners trying to make several nested loops by using `loop` instruction (and MASM). These are probably some stupid teacher minds how to make nested loops in assembly.

So, stop this! It is a bad practice at all. Forget about `loop` instruction and use separate registers for the loop counters. It is so easy and clear:

```
        mov  edx, 1000
loop1:
        mov  ecx, 2000
loop2:
        mov  ebx, 3000
loop3:
        ......
        dec  ebx
        jnz  loop3

        dec  ecx
        jnz  loop2

        dec  edx
        jnz  loop1
```

Also, check what registers `gotoxy` and `writechar` procedures preserve, because they probably change some registers. Check especially for the registers you use in the loops.

Comment: yea but i have use loops for this specific problem.Can you see any errors in the above code.

Comment: @ngoche See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `push ecx` under `row:` label, the last `pop ecx` before `loop` is eating values of the stack, as there are no pushes.

Also you should follow @johnfound answer as those are good recomendations (dec+jnz and the subroutines might modify register values).

Edit:

Also, the `mov ecx, a` and `b` and `d` is actually using the address of the variables which could be very big, should be `mov ecx, [a]` or maybe `mov ecx, dword ptr [a]` (asm rusty). Maybe the `inc` and `dec` may need similar treatment

Comment: I did as you say but its still the same.